# tomcat does not pick the context.xml, it is getting coopied to CATALINA_HOME> conf>Catalina>localhost though

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, context.xml

My context.xml (in META_INF) folder looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Context path="MY_CONTEXT_NAME" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/MY_APP_NAME"
        debug="0" privileged="true">

</Context>
```

The problem is, context.xml is getting copied to the CATALINA_HOME> conf>Catalina>localhost folder when I deploy my application war via tomcat manager. However, it is somehow still deploying from default context, that is , app_war_name.

Earlier, it was not even getting copied to localhost folder, I removed the default context.xml form tomcat 6.0>conf folder. After that, the file is at least getting copied. However, the deployment is not happening from the explicit context.xml.

My server.xml host entry looks like this :

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" >
  </Host>
```

Comment: You have a spelling error autoDeploy="fasle" instead of autoDeploy="false"

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but correcting the typo did not help. I think, that might have happened while trying to make it work by marking it true then again back to false...it does not help but :( I tried to check various other links here.. but not sure whats wrong I am doing...

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for the path element of the Context element. It states quite clearly

> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in
>   server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from
>   the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.
>
> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute
>   must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

Then read the documentation for the docBase element.

> The value of this field must not be set unless the Context element is
>   defined in server.xml or the docBase is not located under the Host's
>   appBase.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for citing this. Few points to make myself more clear: #1. My requirement is to make tomcat override the default context path(which is usually the war file name) and hence the context.xml. #2 I am referring the doc: [link] (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) #3 This was working for me in tomcat5.x, however in tomcat 6.0, the same thing is not working.

Comment: I think I get your point when I read at :[link] http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment , but does that mean I cannot do like this at all? Given, it was working in tomcat 5.x , it should also work in tomcat 6. Basically, I want to define my context for application the same way we can define using application.xml in websphere.

Comment: Then you have to a) locate the WAR outside the appBase and b) place an appropriately named context.xml file in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/

Comment: Ok...I tried to that a) placed WAR in C:\MyProject\MyApp.war b) Put the context.xml by renaming to My#Desired#context#URL.xml (changing the docBase to point to externally placed war file i.e. C:\MyProject\MyApp.war) in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/ and started tomcat,  it got deployed successfully, the desired context path (My/Desired/context/URL) can be seen on tomcat manager, but on clicking on this , I get 404 error. Does this means the war did not actually deployed/extracted in the tomcat/webapps? Or, do I need to define a context element in server.xml?

Comment: I came across this post on coderanch : [link] http://www.coderanch.com/t/554169/Tomcat/set-context-path-application-xml . As per this discussion it seems its not possible to achieve this in tomcat 6!!! Is that ture?? I wonder...

Comment: If the app is shown as started in the Manager then the 404 is being caused by some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you deploy again with new context or changed context you need to un-deploy first/ or remove context.xml from conf/.../localhost/yourapp.xml