# Web Application does not appear to deploy properly on remote tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have a Java Web application that when deployed through eclipse or through copy/paste of .war file into local tomcat will deploy properly and I can use the web application.  I am attempting to deploy this application on a GCE instance with tomcat installed.  With the remote tomcat stopped, I have copied the .war file into the webapps folder, as I did with my local tomcat, and started tomcat.  I can see a message in catalina.out that it is deploying the web application archive and I can view the webapps folder to see that the war has been exploded (everything in this folder seems correct).  I do not however see any of the springframework messages that my local tomcat/eclipse deployments of the webapp create, and I receive a 404 when I try to go to the application home page on the remote tomcat.  I have no idea where to begin to look to find what is wrong with my deployment of the web application.

**Update**

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] {WebMvcConfig.class,RestAppConfig.class,MySQLConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {    
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[] {"/*"};
}
```

This is my WebInitialier calss for the annotation config.  I have SpringMVC configured in the WebMVC, configuration for a RESTful service as well as configuration for a MySQL database.  I changed the log level in my log4j.xml to debug for everything and while I have been very bad about actually logging anything my deployment on the remote tomcat server does not appear to implement any of the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put yourApp.xml file inside Catalina_HOME/conf/localhost folder 
refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249969/tomcat-does-not-pick-the-context-xml-it-is-getting-coopied-to-catalina-home-co).

Comment: I don't think I understand....what .xml file is this?  I haven't dealt with an app.xml...nor can I seem to find this localhost folder you mention.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 message tells you only that resource you are trying to find is not available on that URL, and there might be multiple reasons for that coming to my mind:

1) your applications is not deployed to tomcat properly. You might check this if you have some logs in your application and check in {tomcat-home}/logs/catalina.log if application is deployed properly.

2) you are not using good URL.

3) It could be the problem with GCE instance which might blocks external access to you web application. In that case you should allow access on port 8080 from your web address. If you didn't already do this, then it's very likely the problem, as by default this port should be blocked for external access. You could try to telnet tomcat to check if this is the case, or you can check {tomcat-home}/logs/localhost_access_log to see if your requests reached tomcat. If you see something like:

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2015:09:28:25 -0700] "GET /RESTfulExample/rest/helloworld HTTP/1.1" 404 1011

it indicates that request have reached tomcat, but this resource doesn't exist there.

Hope this helps,

Zoran

Comment: So I am certain that something is not working during the tomcat deploy but there is no error in the catalina log. As far as the GCE instance I have allowed access through 8080 and have been able to access the ROOT application from the tomcat install.  I am not sure about the whether the url is good or not but am using the same url as I use with my local tomcat, replacing localhost:8080 with the external IP of course.  The problem I think is that none of the request mapping through Spring is occurring during the deployment, but I don't know how to ensure that the mapping happens

Comment: Do you use Spring security? What kind of resources you have in your application? Can you add your Spring configuration?

Comment: I am using Spring MVC and Spring security.  The application is entirely annotation configured......I am not sure how to add the configuration for you.

Comment: You can edit your original post and add your configuration as code example. What I would also suggest is to increase logging level of spring and spring security, so you can follow in your logs what is going on. If you are using in your application log4j for example, you can add log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG and log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG. Afterward, you can follow your catalina log and see if spring security is blocking access to some of the resources.

Comment: It doesn't appear that anything is initialized when my application "deploys"  I see in the catalina log: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/chemsense.war but none of the initialization from Spring (or anything else) is occurring....is there configuration on tomcat somewhere that would tell tomcat to initialize? or is there something I need to add to the application to ensure this initialization?....again this all works fine on ever local instance I have used...it is only this GCE tomcat deployment that seems to be causing the headache.

Comment: Did you build your war file locally, and upload it to the server? If so, can you check if you are using the same Java  for building as the one on the server?

Comment: I am building the war locally with maven.  my local java is 1.7.0_67 and the server java is 1.7.0_79

Comment: You are sure that both local and remote java JDKs are either Oracle Java or OpenJDK? I would still recommend you to try to build it on the server directly, and then to upload that one, just to exclude this as potential reason.

Comment: Server:
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Local:
D:>java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
 
I am not sure enough about how to utilize the GCE instance to build the war file on the server....I have never had such trouble with remote tomcat deployments before

Comment: You have two different versions of Java, so it's very likely to be the cause of the problem. Your local machine has Oracle Java, and remote machine OpenJDK. To compile on the server, you have to upload your source code on the server, navigate to the application root where your pom.xml is and run mvn clean package. That will create .war file in target directory, so you have to copy/paste to tomcat webapp. The other solution would be to reinstall java on one of the machines and use the same one on both machines.